# Use single Charles root certificate on multiple laptops

Tags: android, charles-proxy

To capture network logs we are exporting Charles root certificate in android res/raw and referring that in network_config.xml.

As Multiple developers are working on repo we want to commit certificate and config xml in code. so that other developers will just open configure Charles proxy settings on emulator  and see the network logs.

is this possible or any way to import root certificate in Charles.

Comment: did you found if it's possible?